# Compound modifier with adverb

Tags: adverbs, modifiers, compound-adjectives

In the phrase "highly trained support specialist" should a hyphen be used?

Comment: The adverb 'highly' is modifying an adjective and needs no hyphen to let us know that.

Comment: For the *specific* collocation here, Hyphenated ***highly-trained*** used to be as common as the "separate words" version in British English until just a few decades ago. But almost no-one hyphenates that particular one today (which in any case was only ever done if it came *before* the relevant modified noun; *Our support specialists are all highly trained* would never be hyphenated).

Comment: Highly trained support-specialist - Does it reduce the confusion?

Comment: @RamPillai: No! That would be *completely* wrong! We rarely if ever put a hyphen after a ***noun adjunct*** (which is what "support" is there). No-one ever writes *My **car-radio** doesn't work*, for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: OK; agree to your views!